# Error when Re-Deploying Ear to Websphere 7.0 in myEclipse Blue 10.7.1

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7, myeclipse

I've been rattling my brain on this one today to no avail.

I'm trying to redeploy a project to `websphere`, but whenever I do I get the **error**

> "abc123 could not be redeployed because it could not be completely
>   removed in the undeployment phase..."

There's a bit more to the error, but it just says to stop the server and try again, but my server is already stopped.

When I look into the deployment log I see another error:

> "WASX7280E: An application with name 'abc123' does not exist."

I've tried cleaning the project, removing the deployment, adding it back and there was no change.

Anyone else have any ideas I can try?

Comment: Just a few hints - after you undeploy your project from server, check if your application was fully removed from %PROFILE_ROOT%/installedApps. You can also check via admin console, if application is visible there.

Comment: From the deployment log error, it looks like the deployment was removed, from WAS's point of view, but not all files could be removed for some reason. Next time, check which files remain at the deployment location and see if you can delete them manually. That might give more clues. You could also try upgrading to the latest release (MyEclipse licenses are time based, and don't apply to a particular release), which will have other deployment options, like deploying in the MyEclipse workspace ("in-workspace" deployment mode).